# Django Password reset: new password must be different from any of the last four passwords user has submitted

Tags: python, django, security

I am new to Django, please help me how to implement Password Reset so that new password must be different from any of the last four passwords user has submitted in django :

I am using default django password reset:
urls.py:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$',auth_views.password_reset,      
          name='auth_password_reset'),
```

django/contrib/auth/views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def password_reset(request, is_admin_site=False,
                   template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
                   email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
                   subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                   password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
                   token_generator=default_token_generator,
                   post_reset_redirect=None,
                   from_email=None,
                   current_app=None,
                   extra_context=None):
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = password_reset_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            opts = {
                'use_https': request.is_secure(),
                'token_generator': token_generator,
                'from_email': from_email,
                'email_template_name': email_template_name,
                'subject_template_name': subject_template_name,
                'request': request,
            }
            if is_admin_site:
                opts = dict(opts, domain_override=request.get_host())
            form.save(**opts)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
    else:
        form = password_reset_form()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

Should I create database table to store all the previous passwords of the user or is there any django library which will provide me this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a model and store all the passwords of a user whenever password reset/changed.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import json

class OldPasswords(models.Model):
    user = model.ForeignKey(User)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def setPasswords(self, pwd):
        self.pwd = json.dumps(pwd)

    def getPasswords(self):
        return json.loads(self.pwd)
```

create a signal while password reset/changed and save current password.

for example:

```
from allauth.account.signals import password_changed, password_reset
def send_password_changed_email(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('user')
    if user:
       pwds = OldPasswords.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
       pwds.setPasswords(pwd)
```

After saving to the model, you need to implement custom validator to show validation message when user try the old password while reset:

> - validate(self, password, user=None): validate a password. Return None    if the password is valid, or raise a ValidationError with an
>     error    message if the password is not valid. You must be able to
>     deal with    user being None - if that means your validator can’t run,
>     simply    return None for no error.
> - get_help_text(): provide a help text to explain the requirements to      the user.

Any items in the OPTIONS in AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS for your validator will be passed to the constructor. All constructor arguments should have a default value.

Here’s a basic example of a validator, with one optional setting:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from yourapp.model import OldPasswords 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class PasswordValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, password):
        self.password = password

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        pwd_list = OldPasswords.objects.get(user=user).getPasswords() 
        if password in pwd_list:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("You used this password recently. Please choose a different one."),
                code='password_recently_used',
                params={'min_length': self.min_length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "You used this password recently. Please choose a different one."
        )
```

However, if you decide to store a user’s previous passwords, you should never do so in clear text.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer . Please help me how to use the PasswordValidator in my pass_reset view or in my template.

Comment: Password validation is configured in the AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS setting: `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },]`